# django permission denied on file upload

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm getting errors trying to upload a file with the django admin interface using apache2 and mod_wsgi.

my django settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/mysite/web/media'
```

model image field:

```
image_big = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/images/items/big')
```

rights for folder and subfolders (for testing):

```
ls -l /var/www/mysite/web/media/
drwxrwxrwx 3 webX clientX 4.0K Aug  3 20:21 uploads
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the permissions of the entire directory path to `/var/www/mysite/web/media/`. One of these directories probably doesn't have the required read or execute permissions:

- `/var/www/mysite/web/`
- `/var/www/mysite/`
- `/var/www/`
- `/var/`

Comment: I had the same issue when using WSGI or UWSGI etc and using a socket saved in /tmp folder, fixed this by moving the socket to an other folder , in my case the project root directory